# Big difference in random forest test subset error and other subsets

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, prediction

I'm using R "randomForest" package for predicting stock prices. I have more than 3000 observations and 90 columns.

I have excluded my *last 150 days* from data set and divide the rest of my data to test and train subsets.  so I have three subsets: train, test and current days.

I run the script and fit a model by random forest on my train subset, and then predict with test subset. 
Since i have two classes YES/NO in my target variable, I use following code to see the results :

```
with(data[-train,],table(rf.pred,target))
```

True YES prediction in test subset is usually over 80% but when I use the model to predict in current 150 days, the prediction power is awkward and less than 50%! 
for example :
test subset results:

```
       target
rf.pred  NO YES
    NO  224  16
    YES   3  47
```

current days results:

```
        target
rf.pred2  NO YES
     NO    0   0
     YES 106  44
```

I want to know why the test and current days result differs to this extent?

Comment: Looks like it's classifying everything in one class, you may have some errors in your code. Also, is this is time series data?

Comment: No this is just a sample of results. it can classify in both classes in test and current days. Yes it is a time series data

Comment: I don't think we can answer this without a reproducible example.